# Default task options for all grunt tasks

Tags: gruntjs

I specify the `nonull: true` option for every grunt task:

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  copy {
    nonull: true,
    src: [],
    dest: '',
  },
  jshint {
    nonull: true,
    src: [],
    dest: '',
  },
  uglify {
    nonull: true,
    src: [],
    dest: '',
  },
});
```

Is it possible to specify "default" task options - so I can specify `nonull:true` once for all tasks?